# Poner en negrita texto que cargo de SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

Intento poner en negrita solamente el texto que recibo de `SharedPreference` pero no sé cómo hacerlo correctamente, esto es lo que siempre he hecho pero sobre un texto, no sobre uno cargado de `SharedPreferences` y por lo que veo así no es posible.

```
conf.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hola," + " " + <b> prefs.getString("nombrepersona", "") </b> + "," + " " + "texto2");
```

Alguien me puede ayudar? El error es claro, que no reconoce **< b> < /b>**

Comment: Y si usas <strong>? xd

Comment: Buenas noches, creo que esta bien como lo estas haciendo, solo faltaría las comillas en lo "<b>" y "</b>" algo así como 
    conf.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hola," + " " + "<b>"+ prefs.getString("nombrepersona", "") +"</b> "+ "," + " " + "texto2");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debe realizarse de esta forma:

```
 conf.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hola,  <b>" + prefs.getString("nombrepersona", "") + "</b>, texto2");
```

No es necesario concatenar varios strings, y recuerda que los tags html son convertidos, por lo tanto deben ser definidos como string.